# Программная загрузка изображений Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь сделать изображение для кастомной таксономии, вернее для каждого ее элемента(термина). Есть ли какая либо функция, позволяющая загрузить изображение в медиа библиотеку и возвращающая либо URL загруженного файла, либо ID в базе? Ничего подобного не нашел.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[media_sideload_image()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/media_sideload_image)

Пример с возвращением id:

```
media_sideload_image( 'http://vk.com/image.jpg', $post_id, $desc, 'id' );
```

Для возврата адреса картинки - нужно передать 4 параметром 'src' вместо id.

Если нужно загрузить не с урла то можно юзать [media_handle_upload()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/media_handle_sideload)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110400/discussion-on-answer-by------wordp).

Comment: @AK Как раз тревоги хотел ставить.